# Listening for click/touch events in SKScene on MacOS in a SwiftUI SpriteView

Tags: macos, swiftui, sprite-kit, skscene, nsevent

I'm trying to intercept mouse click events inside `SpriteKit` `SKScene` inside a a `SwiftUI` `SpriteView` in `Mac OS`.  Overriding `touchesBegun()` that accepts an `NSEvent` object is never called when I click mouse inside the view.  `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to true.  What am I missing?  Running in Xcode 13.2 with deployment target 12.1 for Mac OS.

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

class MyScene : SKScene {
    override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
        print(event)
    }
}

var scene : MyScene {
    let r = MyScene()
    r.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    r.size = .init(width: 500, height: 500)
    r.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    r.backgroundColor = .orange
    return r
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView.init(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS `SKScene` inherits from `NSResponder`, so we override mouse handlers, like

```
class MyScene : SKScene {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {  // << here !!
        print(event)
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 14 / macOS 12.5

Comment: Thanks for the `// << here !!` otherwise I wouldn't have seen it